# Opening file always returns "-1" in QtSpim

Tags: mips, mips32, qtspim

I'm working on a university project where we have to write Data to a file via MIPS. I get everything to run on **MARS**, but on **QtSpim**, just opening a file always returns an error:

```
.data
file_name: .asciiz "test.pgm"

#
# main
#

.text
.globl main

main:
    # Open File in write mode
    li    $v0, 13           # $v0 = 13, option for opening file
    la    $a0, file_name    # $a0 = &file_name
    li    $a1, 1            # $a1 = 1, write-flag
    li    $a2, 0            # $a2 = 0, mode is ignored
    syscall                 # open File, save descriptor to $v0

    jr $ra                  # return
```

When I run this in QtSpim step by step I get a `-1` in `$v0` after the `syscall`.
Any ideas, why **QtSpim** can't run this? I'm on **Windows 10, QtSpim version 9.1.17**, although the same version on **LinuxMint 18** has the same problem. Any help appreciated, for now I'll just run everything on MARS, but we have to hand in something that works on QtSpim.

---

### **UPDATE**

It seems to work when I use absolute paths, but the file must exist in order to open it in write mode. Is there a way to create the file if it doesn't exist?

Comment: And yeah, I know I have to close the file and such, I just copied the code relevant for this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, after a lot of trial and error, it seems to work when I open the file with Flag 0x41 and mode 0x1FF.

If I understand it correctly, 0x41 is for write with create and 0x1FF for the correct permissions.

```
main:
    # Open File in write mode
    li    $v0, 13           # $v0 = 13, option for opening file
    la    $a0, file_name    # $a0 = &file_name
    li    $a1, 0x41         # $a1 = 0x41, write-flag with create
    li    $a2, 0x1FF        # $a2 = 0, permissions
    syscall                 # open File, save descriptor to $v0

    jr $ra                  # return
```

And absolute paths, apparently QtSpim can't even write into it's own directory when started as admin, so really only absolute paths work.

Answer (score 0):

Relative paths in QtSpim are based on the directory it is executed from, which may be a different one than the location of your code or the image.